# Can´t make window fade using javascript or add transition effect in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been having issues regarding the usage of the `fadeOut` function in order to add an effect whenever I close the window pop up message.

At the same time, I've tried adding a transition effect to the div in CSS but it didn't work either. My idea was to add this fading effect to the `if` statement in JavaScript part but that didn't work.

```css
.window {
  position: fixed;
  border-width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: url(images/blue-abstract-noise-free-website-background-image.jpg);
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 476px;
  height: 276px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 2.82px 1.8px rgba(209, 55, 55, 0.486), 0px 3px 5.88px 0.12px rgba(211, 49, 49, 0.514);
}

.layover {
  background-color: rgba(100, 99, 92, 0.699);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.yesandno {
  height: 80px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 217px;
}

.yes {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
  left: 100px;
}

.yes>button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(129, 127, 127, 0.808);
}

.no {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
  right: 300px;
}

.no>button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(129, 127, 127, 0.808);
}

.langmessage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="window" id="win">
      <div class="layover">
        <div class="h2">
          <h2>Oops!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="yesandno">
          <figure class="yes">
            <button onclick="window.location.href= 'espanol.html';">Si</button>
          </figure>
          <figure class="no">
            <button onclick id="buttonn">No</button>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="langmessage">
          Hemos detectado que el idioma de su ordenador se encuentra en español. ¿Le gustaría utilizar la versión en español de nuestro sitio web?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var lang = navigator.language;
    if ("" + lang == "es-US") {
      var div = document.getElementById("win");
    }
    var button = document.getElementById("buttonn")
    buttonn.onclick = function() {
      var div = document.getElementById("win");
      if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";

      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `fadeOut()` method, you would have to include `jQuery` into your project but you could also manually program it yourself using plain javascript. Below are two solutions, one using `jQuery` and another with plain `javascript`.

**jQuery solution:**

Note: If using `jQuery`, you could then rewrite parts of your code like `document.getElementById("win")` to just `$("#win")`, etc. but that runs out of the scope of the question.

```js
var lang = navigator.language;
if ("" + lang == "es-US") {
  var div = document.getElementById("win");
}

var buttonn = document.getElementById("buttonn");

buttonn.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("win");
  if (div.style.display !== "none") {
    $("#win").fadeOut();
  }
}
```

```css
.window {
  position: fixed;
  border-width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: url(images/blue-abstract-noise-free-website-background-image.jpg);
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 476px;
  height: 276px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 2.82px 1.8px rgba(209, 55, 55, 0.486), 0px 3px 5.88px 0.12px rgba(211, 49, 49, 0.514);
}

.layover {
  background-color: rgba(100, 99, 92, 0.699);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.yesandno {
  height: 80px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 217px;
}

.yes {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
  left: 100px;
}

.yes>button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(129, 127, 127, 0.808);
}

.no {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
  right: 300px;
}

.no>button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(129, 127, 127, 0.808);
}

.langmessage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="window" id="win">
    <div class="layover">
      <div class="h2">
        <h2>Oops!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="yesandno">
        <figure class="yes">
          <button onclick="window.location.href= 'espanol.html';">Si</button>
        </figure>
        <figure class="no">
          <button onclick id="buttonn">No</button>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="langmessage">
        Hemos detectado que el idioma de su ordenador se encuentra en español. ¿Le gustaría utilizar la versión en español de nuestro sitio web?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Vanilla JavaScript solution:**

```js
var lang = navigator.language;
if ("" + lang == "es-US") {
  var div = document.getElementById("win");
}
var buttonn = document.getElementById("buttonn");

buttonn.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("win");
  if (div.style.display !== "none") {
    fadeOutPopup();
  }
}
    
function fadeOutPopup() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("win");
  var fade = setInterval(function () {
      if (!elem.style.opacity) {
          elem.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (elem.style.opacity > 0) {
          elem.style.opacity -= 0.2;
      } else {
          clearInterval(fade);
      }
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
.window {
  position: fixed;
  border-width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: url(images/blue-abstract-noise-free-website-background-image.jpg);
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 476px;
  height: 276px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 2.82px 1.8px rgba(209, 55, 55, 0.486), 0px 3px 5.88px 0.12px rgba(211, 49, 49, 0.514);
}

.layover {
  background-color: rgba(100, 99, 92, 0.699);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.yesandno {
  height: 80px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 217px;
}

.yes {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
  left: 100px;
}

.yes>button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(129, 127, 127, 0.808);
}

.no {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
  right: 300px;
}

.no>button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(129, 127, 127, 0.808);
}

.langmessage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="window" id="win">
    <div class="layover">
      <div class="h2">
        <h2>Oops!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="yesandno">
        <figure class="yes">
          <button onclick="window.location.href= 'espanol.html';">Si</button>
        </figure>
        <figure class="no">
          <button onclick id="buttonn">No</button>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="langmessage">
        Hemos detectado que el idioma de su ordenador se encuentra en español. ¿Le gustaría utilizar la versión en español de nuestro sitio web?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!. Very well explained, hope you have a good day!.